# Why is my code generating two gameObjects(instead of one) at a time when one gameObject out of the Camera view is destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing Scripts for flappy bird type game on my own(best way to learn unity scripting).
To optimize perfromance i want to generate only 5 Obstacle gameObjects(ObjectsOnScreen) at a time.So i wrote a code to destroy gameObject when its 16 units away from the player.And also to generate only one new Obstacle when there are less than 5 ObjectsOnScreen.
But my code is destroying one obsatcle and at the same time generating two objects (instead of one).So ultimately the objects will increase over time intead of remaining constant.
Please tell me mistakes in my code.thanks in advance.

```
 //GameManager script::

    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

static public int ObjectsOnScreen = 0;
public float poleDistance;
public int gapWidth;
static public bool reset=false;
float x = 8;
int gap;
public GameObject obstacle;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(reset)
        {
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        if(ObjectsOnScreen<5)
        {
            gap = Random.Range(-6, 6);
            GenerateObstacle(x, gap);
            x += poleDistance;
            Debug.Log("gap = " + gap);
            ObjectsOnScreen++;
        }
    }

    void GenerateObstacle(float x , float gap)
    {
        GameObject Top = Instantiate(obstacle, new Vector3(x, 8, 0) , Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject Bottom = Instantiate(obstacle, new Vector3(x, -8, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Top.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, (8 - gap)-gapWidth, 1);
        Bottom.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, -(8 + gap)+gapWidth, 1);
    }
}

//Obstacle Script::

public class ObstacleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject player;
    void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if ((transform.position.x - player.transform.position.x) <= -16)
        {
            GameManager.ObjectsOnScreen--;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        PlayerScript player = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerScript>();
        if(player!=null)
        {
            GameManager.reset = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, one possible optimization is to generate 5 objects up front and put them in an array. You can disable them via code so they don't render, the instead of instantiating / deleting objects you can just move them to the new position then enable / disable them. That's called "instancing". You create a fixed number of instances and then re-use them to limit allocations and GC cleanups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling instantiate twice in the `GenerateObstacle` function which will instantiate two objects (instead of one) of course...

```
GameObject Top = Instantiate(obstacle, new Vector3(x, 8, 0) , Quaternion.identity);
GameObject Bottom = Instantiate(obstacle, new Vector3(x, -8, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

But then you're doing `ObjectsOnScreen++`, which only increments by one. Then later the two obstacles delete themselves, which effectively decrements twice.

You should probably increment by two `ObjectsOnScreen += 2` to get an accurate count.